# FAQ section - Algorithm for showing

Tags: angularjs, web

I'm writing this website with an FAQ-section. I've been fiddling abit with how the different questions are scored, in order to display the question, that most people wonder about, on top.

At the moment, I have created a counter that is incremented each time someone presses the question, and the list of questions is sorted in descending order.

My question is: Is there a better way to score these FAQ-questions? For example a combined counter and rating or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rating should play no role in the FAQ algorithm. The rating is feedback for you: if a question/answer pair is repeatedly rated poorly, you should improve its quality.

The FAQ questions should be the ones that your visitors ask most often, so a simple hit counter is a good place to start. You should also consider ways to include questions that you often receive via phone or email or other feedback methods.

A lot of sites rely on manual maintenance of the FAQ, but I prefer an automated or partially automated approach for several reasons:

1. Staff is not always involved in the question/answer process, especially if you have a robust set of questions/answers online.
2. Manually-maintained lists become tedious and therefore receive less attention than they should.
3. Automated metrics often reveal customer behavior that isn't noticed or expected by staff.

Answer (score 1):

What if you let the support staff arrange the FAQs. Because they get the extra phone calls and know the most popular questions.

So i would like the FAQs to be arranged manually by the support staff.